# Xcode(Swift)でのセグエを使わない画面遷移について

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

Xcode 6 + Swift で、 セグエを使用しない画面遷移をしたいのですが、ビルドしても上手く遷移しません。セグエなしで画面遷移するしようとして、遷移先のストーリーボード上の画面の `Storyborad ID` に `next` という名前で設定した場合、コードは以下のようで合っているでしょうか?

お詳しい方がいましたらご回答宜しくお願い致します。

```js
import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @IBAction func nextPage() {
            //nextと名付けた画面に遷移したい
            // var nex = UIViewController()
            var nex : AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("next")
            self.presentViewController(nex as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
```

【補足】
ちなみにビルドしたときに、

```js
var nex : AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("next")
```

のところで「"UIStoryboard?" does not have member named "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier"」と表示されてしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.storyboard` が返す `UIStoryboard?`（オプショナル）は `UIStoryboard` そのものではないので、そのままメソッド `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` を呼び出すことはできません：
[storyboard - UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/storyboard)

オプショナルは存在しない可能性のある値を表すもので、メソッドを呼び出すには、何らかの方法で値が存在することを確定させる（アンラップ）必要があります。

アンラップの仕方については、（私の説明と少し違うところがあるかもしれませんが）次の記事を参考にしてみてください：
[[Swift] Optional 型についてのまとめ Ver2 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/cotrpepe/items/518c4476ca957a42f5f1#optional-%E5%9E%8B%E3%81%AF%E9%9D%9E-optional-%E5%9E%8B%E3%81%A8%E5%90%8C%E3%81%98%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E6%89%B1%E3%81%88%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Answer (score 1):

遷移元のViewControllerと遷移先のViewControllerが同じStoryboard上にあれば、問題ないと思います。

遷移元のViewControllerと遷移先のViewControllerが同じStoryboard上にない場合は、以下で遷移するはずです。

```
@IBAction func nextPage() {
    //nextと名付けた画面に遷移したい
    // var nex = UIViewController()
    var nex = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboardのファイル名", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("next") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(nex, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```