# 画面遷移にストーリーボードを使用しない場合にAppDelegateに書くべきコードを教えてください

Tags: swift

**編註**: 前提として、画面のデザインはストーリーボードで行い、遷移のみをコードで行おうとしています。

AppDelegate上にて以下のような画面遷移を実装する場合、ビルドは出来るのですが
identifierを入れていないため、画面は真っ黒のままです。
どのようにidentifierを書き込んだらいいのでしょうか？

```js
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var viewController: ViewController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
        return true
    }
```

【補足】
遷移先のViewControllerは全てStoryboardで作成し、コードで書いたものではないため、
この質問([Xcode(Swift)でのセグエを使わない画面遷移について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/xcodeswift)%E3%81%A8%E5%90%8C%E3%81%98%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)。
storyboardでの実装のため、ViewControllerとAppDelegateの指示がバラバラになっていて、ビルド成功しても、画面が黒くなってしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問文の編集のためにお聞きしたいのですが、これはストーリーボードのエントリーポイントを使わずに起動時のビューコントローラを決めたいとか、そういう意図のコードですか？　「identifierを入れていないため、画面は真っ黒のままです。」という質問内容で予測されている原因も、それのみでは不足しているため、いくらか修正したほうがよいように思います。

Comment: 参考になるか分かりませんが、一読して頂けると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

前提としてAppDelegateでやる処理は

- `self.window`の作成
- `self.window.rootViewController`の設定
- `self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()`の呼び出し

だったと記憶しています。

それから質問の`UIViewController`は`storyboardWithName:bundle:`で`UIStoryboard`を取得して`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`で得られるので、結局

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboard", bundle: nil)
self.viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier")
self.window!.rootViewController = self.viewController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

でしょうか。

`"storyboard"`は拡張子を除くストーリーボードのファイル名（例:「Main.storyboard」->「Main」）、`"identifier"`はストーリーボードでUIViewControllerに設定したStoryboard IDです。

Comment: 三行目のコードで、「instantiate」の部分でエラーが出てしまいました。そこで、この行の最後文に「as ViewController」をインサートしたら、ビルドできたのですが画面は変わらず黒いままです。
やはり遷移先のViewControllerを一度、AppDelegate内で定義した方がよいのでしょうか？

Comment: `as ViewController`でビルドできるということは、ViewControllerクラスは作られているんですね？　であれば、ストーリボードで該当のビューコントローラのIdentity Inspectorを開いて、「Class」欄が「ViewController」になっているか確認してください。また、あなたが追加した型キャストを`as? ViewController`（asにハテナをつける）にしてみてください。

Comment: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let currentController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Storyboard ID") as ViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = currentController`
これでいけるはずです。「as ViewController」のつけ場所に注目。
それよりも、Storyboard上で、ViewControllerインスタンスの「Storyboard ID」が、コードとマッチしてないような気がしますよ。

Comment: Harawo様、dynamicCastClassにて「0x10eee88ad:  movq   %rdi, %rax」という部分でエラーが出てしまいました。コードとマッチしていないというのは「Class」の設定が出来ていない、ということでしょうか？ちなみに「StoryboardID」は設定できているはずなのですが・・・・・

Comment: こちらは、ちゃんとXcode上でコードを書き、iOSシミュレータで実行した結果を載せています。わたしからいえるのは、そのエラーはこちらでは発生していないことだけです。

Comment: ・・・もう一度だけ聞きますけど、ストーリーボードで「Class」欄が「ViewController」になっていますか？　もし空欄だったり全く別のクラスであれば`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional`で落ちますよ。それともどこを確認したらいいのかわからずにいますか？

Comment: 「Custom Class」の「Class」ですか？「ViewController」を指定しています。

Comment: そこです。そこが正しくて、@Harawo さんの提示したコードで落ちるのが現状ですか。一度「Product」-「Clean」の実行と、iPhoneシミュレータから当該アプリを削除して、ビルドできますか？　それでダメな場合はストーリーボードのソースコードを補足として追記してもらえれば何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: @dokubeko様、「Clean」を実行し、一旦アプリを削除して再ビルドしたら成功致しました。
回答してくださった@pgrho様、@Harawo様、@dokubeko様、有り難うございました。